# scalate templates won`t work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, scalate

couple days ago I've created spring webapp with scalate template endine. Everything worked great but from yesterday I can't get it running. This is what I get

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/fusesource/scalate/spring/view/ScalateUrlView, method: renderMergedTemplateModel signature: (Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V) Incompatible argument to function
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:839)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/fusesource/scalate/spring/view/ScalateUrlView, method: renderMergedTemplateModel signature: (Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V) Incompatible argument to function
org.fusesource.scalate.spring.view.ScalateViewResolver.buildView(ScalateViewResolver.scala:41)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:419)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:158)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:384)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:77)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1078)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

When i'll switch back in my servlet-context.xml to jsp it will run but on scalate i can't

this is my servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean class="org.fusesource.scalate.spring.view.ScalateViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/scalate/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".ssp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="org.fixus.springer" />
```

please help

Comment: What changed between yesterday and today?  What got updated or changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem. I`ve deleteed from my pom.xml scalate-core and it fixed the problem